# How can i use this javascript code without interfering with other forms

Tags: javascript

I created two forms on my website, but when i submit it redirects automatically, i want to prevent this.

I have a javascript code here that does exactly what i need, but it works in all forms on my website,  i just need this code working in a specific form, because i have two forms, one called login, and other one called cart, and when i click on login button, it doesnt redirect, because of the script, it works for both forms, and i just want this script working in a specific form, in this case, cart.

I hope you understand, i dont speak english very well.

My Javascript code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready( function () {
         $('form').submit( function () {
             var formdata = $(this).serialize();
             $.ajax({
                 type: "POST",
                 url: "carrinho.php",
                data: formdata,
             });
            return false;
        });
    }); </script>
```

My html code:

```
 <form name="comprar" method="post" action="carrinho.php">
           <input name="id_txt" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" />
            <input name="nome" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $nome; ?>" />
            <input name="preco" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $preco; ?>" />
            <input name="quantidade" type="hidden" value="1" />


            <input name="Comprar" type="submit" class="Adicionar" value="" />
            </form>
```

Carrinho means cart, im building a ecommerce store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
         $("form[name='comprar']").submit( function () {
             var formdata = $(this).serialize();
             $.ajax({
                 type: "POST",
                 url: "carrinho.php",
                data: formdata
             });
            return false;
        });
    });
```

Use `$("form[name='comprar']")` to access particular form. Change form name according to your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Use an [attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) to select only the desired form.  Also note that extra `,` is going to cause problems in IE < 9.

```
$("form[name='comprar']").submit( function () {
    var formdata = $(this).serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "carrinho.php",
        data: formdata,  //remove this comma
    });
    return false;
 });
```

Comment: That extra `,` passed my eyes un-noticed. +1 to you (if I had votes left), since I don't I remove my answer which is the same, but one `,` too long :)

Comment: @Sergio No need to remove your answer.  They all help.